# node.js share dynamic variables between modules

Tags: node.js, express

I have a variable named **number_of_clusters** which must be updated periodically. **number_of_clusters** must also be shared with other modules to read it. how can I assure that reading modules will read a fresh copy of this variable each time they access that?
I dont want to use database to share this variable so I thought I could share it via process.env

```
process.env.number_of_clusters = 1;
```

is it a good practice?

Comment: Have you tested this out? Global variables don't magically fall behind the process, they will be up to date all the time, unless you asynchronously update it.

Comment: @SterlingArcher No I have not tested that. and i really like to know what are the down sides of using global variables and update them asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your searching for a global variable:

```
global. number_of_clusters = 1
```

However using a database or a file would probably be a nicer solution.

Comment: what is the benefit of using a global variable than defining the global variable on process.env?

Comment: good question. I would say you cannot have name collisions with the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading/writing in a file?

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("/path/to/file", "whatever", function(err) {
    console.log("The file was saved!");
}); 
fs.readFile('/path/to/file', 'utf8', function(err, contents) {
    console.log(contents); // -> whatever
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the other modules are running as part of the same Nodejs process,
you can just export a `getter` to other modules which will get the fresh value of `number_of_clusters` for them.
Like:

```
function get_number_of_clusters() {
  return number_of_clusters;
}

module.exports = { get_number_of_clusters };
```

Now in other modules, you need to import this module and call this method, like:

```
var getter = require('path/to/above/module').get_number_of_clusters;
var number_of_clusters = getter();
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use socket.io to store the variable on the server and have it emit to all pages.

Comment: Sorry about that! Here is the guide for getting started with a quick chat app: https://socket.io/get-started/chat/